# CABasicAnimation appears offscreen by some margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, cabasicanimation

So I am trying CABasicAnimation for the very first time. I am trying to apply it on a layer and I want layer to interpolate from one point to another. I initially set a negative x coordinate and I put the animation on the infinite. It is working but then it takes few seconds to appear on screen. So it should completely go to the end and start again. Following is code

```
[[self bgImageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_dynamicwx_cloudyday_3.jpg"]];
for (CALayer *layer in self.emitterView.layer.sublayers) {
    [layer removeAllAnimations];
}

[self.emitterView.layer removeAllAnimations];
NSArray *subLayers = self.emitterView.layer.sublayers;
for (CALayer *layer in subLayers) {
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
}

CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
UIImage *layerImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2_cloud.png"];
mask.bounds = CGRectMake(self.emitterView.bounds.origin.x, self.emitterView.bounds.origin.y, layerImg.size.width, layerImg.size.height);
mask.contents = (id)layerImg.CGImage;

CGPoint fromPoint = CGPointMake(-layerImg.size.width, 0);
CGPoint toPoint = CGPointMake(layerImg.size.width, 0);

mask.position = fromPoint; // CoreAnimation animations do *not* persist

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:fromPoint];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toPoint];
animation.duration = 150;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;

[mask addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
[self.emitterView.layer addSublayer:mask];
```

Basically I'm trying the cloud animation, where the cloud is floating over the screen. I'm pretty sure I got some concept wrong here for basic animation. As the duration is 150 (it is supposed to be subtle), it takes forever to show up the animation. Seems like position is offscreen by more than what I have given. Image I am using for the layer is 728 by 368.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW15)

> The position property is located in the middle of the layer.

The code you're using assumes that position is located at the top left of the layer. You can easily fix this by changing your to and from points:

```
CGPoint fromPoint = CGPointMake(-layerImg.size.width*0.5, layerImg.size.height*0.5);
CGPoint toPoint = CGPointMake(layerImg.size.width*1.5, layerImg.size.height*0.5);
```

Now your layer will animate from off-screen left to off-screen right.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) I didn't read the position documentation properly. This worked. Thanks a lot. :)